# Debugging Linux LKM: how to force probe()

Tags: probe

When you insert LKM with insmod it does not seem to execute defined probe() function. What do I need to do to trigger it?

Background: trying to create driver for MAX14830 for old kernel (2.6.39). Cannot use one available (max310x.c) because of old kernel, no support for regmap etc. In the source tree of old kernel there is max3107 driver (same thing, but for 1 serial port, while 14830 has 4). Both drivers use probe functions for initialization, as the SOC communicates with MAX chip over spi. I want to develop driver as LKM first.

What could be my problem?